# Как сделать эффект ретуши для элемента в android?

Tags: android, kotlin

В моем случае это кнопка. Вот посмотрите пожалуйста на картинку, я пробовал с тенью что то сделать, но ничего не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код кнопки:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/mnemBtn"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/slider_btn"
        android:letterSpacing="0.05"
        android:lineHeight="21sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:shadowColor="@color/main_blue"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="50"
        android:elevation="68dp"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/main_blue"
        android:shadowRadius="500"
        android:text="@string/mnem_phrase"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white2"
        android:textFontWeight="700"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
         />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/prvBtn"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/slider_btn2"
        android:letterSpacing="0.05"
        android:lineHeight="21sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="5"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="@string/private_key"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/login_black"
        android:textFontWeight="700"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />
```

Comment: не понятно, что вы хотите, "ретушь" понятие растяжимое

Comment: Я же на картинке стрелкой показал, вот надо такое. Я не знаю как это называется, заказчик говорит ретушь и чтоб было обязательно.

Comment: все равно не понял - там просто кнопка с круглыми краями, что вы хотите напишите словами

Comment: Внизу кнопки такая как тень, но это не тень, вот ее надо сделать. Ну может как то можно было задник сделать, но в figme оно никак нельзя захватить.